# Why does this C++ code-snippet segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int recur(int x) {
    1 and recur(--x);
    cout << x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    recur(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does '1 and recur(--x);' do? never seen it

Comment: @Powe: `and` is an alternate token for `&&`. The line itself doesn't make much sense (the left-side of the AND is always true) and could just be written `recur(--x)`. Here, it is obvious there is no way to terminate. @lorb: To stop the recursion, you need a base case at the top of the function to exist without another call to itself, such as `if (x == 0) return 0;` You could also change `1` to `x`, which will stop evaluation of the right hand side when x is 0.

Comment: @GMan - `1 and` makes sense if you realize it probably should've been `x and`, in which case it short-circuits the recursive call, and more or less becomes equivalent to your `if` statement.

Comment: totally should have been "x and" instead of "1 and". thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1 and recur(--x);
```

is equivalent to

```
recur(--x);
```

Clearly you are making infinite recursive calls which leads to stack overflow followed by segmentation fault.

I *guess* you meant

```
  x and recur(--x);
```

which makes the recursive call only when x is non-zero.

Comment: ...and in a beautifully non-obvious way. Prefer the `if (x <= 0) return 0;` that tzaman suggested because it is more readable and is safer in the event that later code changes cause `x` to skip 0 on its way to negative infinity.

Answer (score 5):

Thats an infinite recursion. So it will seg fault when it runs out of stack space.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a termination condition for the recursion, and so will recurse until you run out of stack space.

Answer (score 2):

`recur` is an infinite loop; you need to put a base condition on there so it stops calling itself.
E.g. (at the top of the function) `if (x <= 0) return 0;`

Also, what's the point of the `1 and` ? It's a no-op... maybe you meant `x and`, which would stop the recursion when `x` reached `0`, provided you only ever called `recur` with a positive number (negative values would still cause the infinite loop).

Comment: Negative values won't cause an infinite loop, but you will likely still blow your stack, so its basically the same thing.

Comment: A recursive function isn't __looping,__ it's __recursing.__ Therefor it isn't an __endless loop,__ but an __endless recursion.__