# What's So Good About Recursion?

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursion or Iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209/recursion-or-iteration)

> To iterate is human, to recurse divine.
>    - L. Peter Deutsch

Why do people favor recursion over iteration, and even go so far as to call it divine, as shown in the quote?  It seems to be over-hyped.  As far as I can tell, recursive code is more difficult to grasp, and therefore maintain.  Additionally, you [run the risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964852/why-infinite-recursion-leads-to-seg-fault) of stack overflows if the compiler doesn't optimize.

Comment: @gnovice Possibly duplicate of *all* of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursion+vs+iteration haha