# C++ segmentation fault and recurrent function

Tags: c++

In this program, I used a recurrent function which is Strlen.
However, prompt tells me that it is

```
zsh: 
segmentation fault  ./Strlen5
```

*Does anyone know why it happens ?*

***My Code:***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t Strlen(char* str) {
    size_t i = 0;
    if (str[i] != '\0') {
        i += 1;
        return 1 + Strlen(str);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void ShowLength(char* str) {
    cout << "length:\"" << str << "\" : " << Strlen(str) << endl; 
}

int main() {
    ShowLength("Hello");
    ShowLength("Titan");
}
```

Comment: You have an infinite recursion.

Comment: You should use `const char *`. Also why not use a loop? Recursion on a long string could result in stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You never increment your pointer. You need to start one index ahead each time you recurse.

```
return 1 + Strlen(str + 1);
```

Also you should use `const char*` instead of `char*`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t Strlen(const char* str) {
    if (str[0] != '\0') {
        return 1 + Strlen(str + 1);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void ShowLength(const char* str) {
    cout << "length:\"" << str << "\" : " << Strlen(str) << endl; 
}

int main() {
    ShowLength("Hello");
    ShowLength("Titan");
}
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/2rbj)

Comment: @Shion the i += 1 in the original was an attempt at that but does not work because you never use I and you dont pass I to the following iteration

Answer (score 1):

By the way the reason you got a segmentation fault is due to how a function call is constructed.

Since you need to pass on the stack the arguments and the pointer to next the instruction after the call you "waste" a portion of your stack every time you call a function (until you return).
This usually is not a problem, but if you call an infinite number of function one after the other you face a stack overflow.

Further reading:
[Why infinite recursion leads to seg fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964852/why-infinite-recursion-leads-to-seg-fault)