# Attempting to traverse a quad tree to determine height

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, segmentation-fault, traversal

I'm currently trying to auto-generate a maze of randomly generated room objects that are linked via pointers in 4 directions - n, s, e, and w.  I begin at Room *home, and build out with each new room having a 1/3 chance in creating a door in each of the other three directions (it of course has a door back to where it came from).  This runs until all "leaves" have three null pointers to the other directions.  I believe the map is being created properly, as I am able to "move around" within it using another function (not included below).  My question is how can I find the height of this structure.  It is essentially a quad-tree.  Here is my code for building the maze and attempting to find the height.  I get a segmentation fault when executing.  If I comment out any three of the four recursive calls in height, it does not fault.

```
void buildMaze(Room *newRoom, char d)
{  
    int rando;

    Room *last = newRoom;

    //coming from south
    if(d == 's')
    {
        newRoom = new Room();
        newRoom->southDoor = last;
        last->northDoor = newRoom;

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 's');//build north room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'w');//build east room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'e');//build west room
    }
    //coming from north
    else if(d == 'n')
    {
        newRoom = new Room();
        newRoom->northDoor = last;
        last->southDoor = newRoom;

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'n');//build south room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'w');//build east room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'e');//build west room
    }
    //coming from east
    else if(d == 'e')
    {
        newRoom = new Room();
        newRoom->eastDoor = last;
        last->westDoor = newRoom;

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 's');//build north room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'n');//build south room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'e');//build west room
    }
    //coming from west
    else if(d == 'w')
    {
        newRoom = new Room();
        newRoom->westDoor = last;
        last->eastDoor = newRoom;

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 's');//build north room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'n');//build south room

        rando = arc4random_uniform(3);
        if(rando == 1)
           buildMaze(newRoom, 'w');//build east room
    }
    //home room always has 4 doors
    else
    {
        buildMaze(newRoom, 's');//build north room
        buildMaze(newRoom, 'n');//build south room
        buildMaze(newRoom, 'w');//build east room
        buildMaze(newRoom, 'e');//build west room
    }
}

//longest distance from home
int height(Room *r)
{
    int n, s, e, w;
    if (r == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        //compute the height of each subtree
        n = height(r->northDoor);
        s = height(r->southDoor);
        e = height(r->eastDoor);
        w = height(r->westDoor);

        //return the largest tree height
        if (n >= s && n >= e && n >= w)
            return (n + 1);
        else if(s >= n && s >= e && s >= w)
            return (s + 1);
        else if(e >= n && e >= s && e >= w)
            return (e + 1);
        else
            return (w + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a high possibility of an almost infinite recursion which may cause the segfault. Please check the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964852/why-infinite-recursion-leads-to-seg-fault

Comment: It'll be easier for you to debug if you figure out where the segfault is. Run it in gdb and see what happens.

Comment: I realized the infinite recursion after I put this away for the night.  Thank you for the confirmation and the link.  It makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Will_Panda says there is infinite recursion because the links back to the room you came from mean you just go round in a recursive loop.

Simplest way to fix is to add a field to you `Room` class to indicate that the room has already been visited as part of the height calculation. Then if `visited` is false before you start your calculation you can use it to avoid infinite recursion. E.g.

```
//longest distance from home
int height(Room *r)
{
    int n, s, e, w;
    if (r == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else if (r->visited) // already been here
        return 0;
    else
    {
        //compute the height of each subtree
        r->visited = true;
        n = height(r->northDoor);
        s = height(r->southDoor);
        e = height(r->eastDoor);
        w = height(r->westDoor);

        //return the largest tree height
        if (n >= s && n >= e && n >= w)
            return (n + 1);
        else if(s >= n && s >= e && s >= w)
            return (s + 1);
        else if(e >= n && e >= s && e >= w)
            return (e + 1);
        else
            return (w + 1);
    }
}
```

Once you know the height you will have to go through all the rooms again clearing all the visited fields

```
//clear visited fields
void clear_visited(Room *r)
{
    if (r == nullptr)
        return;
    else if (!r->visited) // already cleared
        return;
    else
    {
        r->visited = false;
        clear_visited(r->northDoor);
        clear_visited(r->southDoor);
        clear_visited(r->eastDoor);
        clear_visited(r->westDoor);
    }
}
```

Completely untested code.

Comment: I did it by simply passing in the room I came from, so I could avoid going back down that path, similarly to how I built the maze of rooms.  Same result, though,  Thanks for your advice.